# installing 2 ddr2 single channel rams in one channel (asus motherboard); It does not work. why?

Tags: memory, motherboard, hardware-failure

The motherboard has 4 slots (2 yellow and 2 black)
when I install 2 2gb single channel rams in one channel the computer beeps continuously (1 long and 2 short beeps) but if I install rams in 2 channels (each in separate channel), it works.
The rams are exactly the same.

rams: 2GB single channel 800MHZ, Crucial
motherboard: ASUS P5KPL/1600

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What does the manual indicate is the preferred memory configuration?